# Amazon Music PC version - reset the library

Tags: mp3

I'm using the PC version of Amazon Music and I've made the mistake to point it to my current MP3 depot.

The issue is that this depot is a bit messy and I would like to have 2 separate locations: my old and messy mp3 dir with dozens of untagged tunes and 'various' album, and a clean Amazon place, where I can easily browse my albums.

I did not find any way to tell the software to forgot about old songs: I have uninstalled and reinstalled; but settings were kept. I have renamed my music dir, but now I still have the 'Table of Content' of library and errors when I tried to read.

I must be dumb: I didn't find know how to reset the library in order to have a fresh start. How can I do that ?

Comment: What about [this procedure](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201379480) ?

Comment: My online collection is fine. I have an issue with the PC version that has mixed my own personal files and my amazon music.

Comment: I suggest to uninstall the PC version using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), then search the disk for file/folders possibly belonging to it. You may use the [Everything Search Engine](http://www.voidtools.com/) or [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack). Do the same with regedit. Finally, reinstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I trusted too much the uninstall for this app: the database containing details about my music were not uninstalled with it.

These files are here:
C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Amazon Music\Data

I just deleted this dir and then I got a fresh library when I restarted the app.

Thank you @harrymc for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

On a Macintosh, the Data folder is at:

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Amazon Music
```

I deleted the Data folder and also the Amazon Music folder in my main home folder, and I got a new library when I restarted the app.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also reset my preferences, so it started importing all my music from iTunes all over again. Deleting `Data/Library` instead of `Data` kept the preferences, but removed my personal files from the app. (The music I purchased from Amazon was restored, which is what I wanted.)